# Free alternative of TOAD for DB2

Tags: database, db2, toad

I am currently using [Toad for DB2](http://www.toadsoft.com/toaddb2/index.html) to work on my DB2 database. I just wanted to know is there any free alternative to Toad for DB2,

**Note:**
  [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214930/alternatives-to-toad) is posted earlier, but it was for TOAD [ oracle ], none of the solution specified is for DB2 obviously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [AQT](http://www.querytool.com/) or [SquirrelSQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) (depending on your budget and patience).

Comment: Ah, well, Squirrel has code completion (which I like a lot) but the overall handling is a bit better in AQT. Squirrel sometimes likes to hang for a couple of second after restoring it from the task bar. It's nothing major and I do most of my work with Squirrel but I prefer AQT to browse the admin structures (grants, view definitions, active queries and locks, etc).

Comment: Aaron: On the other hand, Oracle's SQLDeveloper only allows one open connection at a time! So it doesn't allow structure browsing while another query is running. SQuirreL does.

Comment: Both AQT and SquirrelSQL can open several connections.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest Aqua Data Studio, it is cool database font end
You can use Aqua Data Studio with many database such as DB2, Oracle, Ms. Access, and etc.

Comment: ADS is fantastic, and it was great while it was free, but their licenses are now $499 for 1 year as of 8/2013. (I realize your post was from almost 4 years ago when it was still free.)

Answer (score 2):

[SQuirreL SQL Client](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) works well. As far as its GUI, their are several different "Look&Feel"s to choose from. (But yeah, it's too busy to use ona netbook, I know.)

Comment: Actually earlier i used Squirrel but IMO it is not having good GUI and enough functionalities. But certainly i can switch back to it.

Answer (score 2):

This thread is pretty old, one year after has been posted
a new client came up:
http://dbeaver.io/
Highly recommended free open-source database administration tool

Comment: How Dbeaver software is not an answer to the OP Question?

Comment: It's a very useful contribution, but not a definitive complete answer that exhaust the question

Comment: anycase thank you, don't misunderstand: it's just a hint

Answer (score 1):

I like [SQLDbx](http://www.sqldbx.com), which handles several flavours of database, including some DB2.  I'm afraid that I'm not familiar with DB2, but their web site says it is compatible with IBM DB2 LUW ® 7.x - 9.x, IBM DB2® z/OS 7.x - 9.x and IBM DB2® iSeries 5.x - 6x.  Some of the functionality for some of these are only available in their Professional edition, and not the free one.

Answer (score 1):

I've used Embarcadero's [DBArtisan](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/dbartisan) in the past. It worked great on our DB2 environment, but was able to work against our SQLServer as well.

Comment: my apologies, I missed that portion of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the next version of Oracle SQL Developer can connect to some flavours of DB2.  More info on [the OTN forum](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=554323) (including a link to the Early Adopter release)